# Add a space after a specific character with php

Tags: php, html, string

I tried Googling and nothing helped. I'm inexperienced with PHP. I hope question is clear.

So what I want is to put a space after a specific character in a string

like from:

```
1234b1
```

to:

```
1234b 1
```

I need a code to do it for me

**NOTE:** No need to spoon-feed me.

Comment: After `b`s? After alpha characters? After non-numerical characters? When?

Comment: Yes. after b I want to make a space. @chris85

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A rather elegant way to do this is using a [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$input = '1234b1';
$pattern = '/b/';
$replacement = '$0 ';
$output = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$input);
```

Running this with PHP's interactive shell:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $input = '1234b1';
php > $pattern = '/b/';
php > $replacement = '$0 ';
php > $output = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$input);
php > echo $output;
1234b 1
```

**EDIT**: in case you want to skip a line, you update `$replacement` with `"\$0\n"`, or if you want HTML new lines: `$0<br>`:

```
$input = 'abbbbasasjscxxxxc';
$pattern = '/c/';
$replacement = "\$0\n"; //'$0<br>' for HTML
$output = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$input);
echo $output;
```

Comment: I believe it's just me but it's not working? And how about skipping a line?

Comment: @Error: there were some errors, now it should work. Tested it on my own machine.

Comment: Thanks Willem! How about skipping a line? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Error: what line? Please update your question and give an example with input and expected output.

Comment: like, for example abbbbasasjsc(Skip a line after c) xxxxc(Skip line) etc.

Comment: Figured it out.$replacement = '$0<br>';

Comment: @Error: it depends on whether you want a string new line, or a HTML new line. For the latter case, you are indeed correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get away with a simple string replace here.

```
$string = '1234b1';
echo str_replace('b', "b<br>\n", $string);
```

Output:

```
1234b
1
```

Demo: <s>https://eval.in/493496</s>https://eval.in/493503

If the character isn't always a `b` though you will need a regex.

A regex approach that will replace any alpha character with the character and a new line.

```
$string = '1234b1';
echo preg_replace('/([a-z])/', '$1' . "<br>\n", $string);
```

If only ever swapping `b` replace `[a-z]` with `b`. The `[]` is a character class meaning the characters inside are allowed the `a-z` is a range of characters.

The `<br>`s are because it appears you are outputting this in a browser; if not those can be removed. Any non-browser will display the `<br>` literally.

Comment: I agree that in case it is only one character, you can use `str_replace` (+1 btw), but indeed as you mention from the moment you want to do more complicated stuff, a regex is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @chris85 how about skipping a line?

Comment: @Error Updated both answers now add a newline after the `b`. If you wanted something different please update your question with a specific example.

Comment: @chris85: no indeed it works. Although - sorry - I think it is a bit asking for trouble. Please do not see this as an offensive comment.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think it is valid because `$` and a number is not a valid variable in PHP. Tests seem to confirm it works in all versions, https://3v4l.org/LMCIl. Updated just to avoid confusion in the future.