# add a new line after a specific characters second iteration in a string with php

Tags: php, html, string

I have a string of that displays like this...

```
L1010,L0072,L005,L0098,L0198,L0198
```

I need to add new line after every second comma

i.e.

```
L1010,L0072,
L005,L0098,
L0198,L0198
```

the string length will always be different but will follow the same pattern as the above i.e. digits comma space digits comma space, etc.

how can I do this with PHP? Is it possible?

At the moment I have it to create a new line after every comma
[Add a space after a specific character with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472869/add-a-space-after-a-specific-character-with-php)

```
$input = L1010,L0072,L005,L0098,L0198,L0198;
$pattern = '/,/';
$replacement = '$0<br>' ;
$output = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$input);
```

how can I do this with PHP? Is it possible?

Thanks

PS, I also found this [Help with regexp replacing every second comma in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889408/help-with-regexp-replacing-every-second-comma-in-the-string) but I'm not sure how to modify it to work in PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php explode every third instance of character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274983/php-explode-every-third-instance-of-character)

Comment: Have you just copy/pasted the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889408/help-with-regexp-replacing-every-second-comma-in-the-string) you linked to? It's a word for word copy with only the language that differs. Btw, that regex would work in PHP as well. Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use explode and then foreach it with array_chunk looping them two and two.
Then implode it back to the format you want.

```
$s = "123, 123, 456, 456, 123, 123";

$arr = explode(",", $s);
$str ="";
Foreach(array_chunk($arr,2) as $sub){
    $str .= trim(implode(",",$sub)) .",<br>\n";
}
Echo $str;
```

Output:

```
123, 123,
456, 456,
123, 123,
```

https://3v4l.org/LQSA9

Comment: Wow I like that one. I should use array chunk much more often then I do now :)

Comment: Yep. You can also use array_splice. It will cut off piece by piece of the array in a size you want. Note splice, not slice.

Comment: Yeah I know these functions, but I rarely use them. Same was the case with array_map and array_walk, but I use them more often now ^^

Comment: Array_map is (as far as I know) just a glorified loop. In the back end there is a loop that handles the values in the array. So usually it's no or very little difference between looping and array_map. But it looks better. And that is generally what "sells" here on SO. I don't think I have ever used array_walk. **I** don't find any need for it.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt `array_map()` and `array_walk()` are actually slower in some situations than using a simple foreach-loop. Many people assume they are better/faster because they are native functions but that can, in some situations, be a false assumption.

Comment: I know what they are, but I think they are sometimes just more convenient to use then doing another loop.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need new regex like this https://regex101.com/r/5YkhQs/1

```
$pattern = '/[0-9]{3},\s[0-9]{3},\s/';
```

If the number can consist of any number of characters, use this:

```
$pattern = '/[0-9]+,\s[0-9]+,\s/';
```

UP. Any characters except comma and space inside the group ))

```
$pattern = '/[^,\s]+,\s[^,\s]+,\s/';
```

Comment: I would use `[0-9]+` instead of `[0-9]{3}`. It makes it more flexible.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes you are right. I just love accuracy))

Comment: What happens if there is an odd number of values?

Comment: @Andreas This will not work. And what if 4 digits is a mistake? Then it will not be noticed.

Comment: @Andreas I did it ))

Answer (score 0):

How about looping over the elements after exploding them?

```
$string = '123, 234, 345, 546, 123, 234';
$elements = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $string));
$newString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) {
    $newString .= $elements[$i] . ', ';
    if ($i % 2 !== 0) {
        $newString .= PHP_EOL;
    }
}

print $newString;
```

Result:

```
123, 234, 
345, 546, 
123, 234,
```

Yes. This is more code then doing a regex. But its better performance if your string is really long.

What it does:

1. split the string by comma
2. loop over all elements and adding them to a new string
3. if $i is divided by 2 and has no rest (every even number), add new line